# read attributes name in C++ using xerces

Tags: c++, xerces

```
void MySAX2Handler::startElement(const   XMLCh* const    uri,
                        const   XMLCh* const    localname,
                        const   XMLCh* const    qname,
                        const   Attributes&     attrs)
{
  char* message = XMLString::transcode(localname);
  cout << "first element: "<< message << endl;
  XMLString::release(&message);
}
```

I want to read attributes of that element, i am not able to display

ex. -

```
<person pname="xyz">
  <dept dname="abc"/>
</person>
```

I want to display attribute name i.e., pname and its value i.e., xyz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classAttributeList.html

```
for (int i=0; i< attrs.getLength(); i++)
{
    std::cout << attrs.getName(i) << std::cout << attrs.getValue(i) << std::endl;
}
```

I'll leave looking up by name and/or transcoding and/or namespace resolutions up to you :)